# What does SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH mean?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

So, I’ve been researching webos, and I’ve came across [this one](https://github.com/Bihan001/Kaisen-OS). In the read me.md file, there was a configuration file that said it required a “SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH”. I also noticed that it was a .json file. What does this mean?

I tried a random .json file, but it didn’t work.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The [instructions](https://github.com/Bihan001/Kaisen-OS#setting-up-development-environmentwithout-using-docker) mention that the environment variable should point to a serviceAccount.json file.

Answer (score 1):

That's an [environment variable](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/). They're a common way to control how things work without having to write config files or "more programming code". You set the value as part of the execution environment, and libraries that use them will pick up on them automatically (and *your* code can see what environment variables are available by accessing [process.env](https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v19/process/#processenv))